# Transaction is not rolled back when RuntimeException occurs

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, transactional

I want contract 1 updated and contract 7 rolled back when method `update2` occur exception. But both contracts were saved success.

If I change `propagation` of `update2` from `REQUIRES_NEW` to `REQUIRED`, it throw exception `"Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only"`

How can I achieve that?

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private ContractRepo contractRepo;

    @Autowired
    ContractService contractService;

    @Transactional(value = "transactionManager2")
    public void update1() {
        CONTRACT con1 = contractRepo.findById("1120180001").get();
        con1.setCONTRACT_DATE(new Date());
        contractRepo.save(con1);

        CONTRACT con7 = contractRepo.findById("1120180007").get();
        try {
            contractService.update2(con7);
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception when calling update2 " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

@Service
public class ContractService {
    @Autowired
    private ContractRepo contractRepo;

    @Transactional(value = "transactionManager2", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void update2(CONTRACT con) {
        con.setCONTRACT_DATE(new Date());
        contractRepo.save(con);
        throw new RuntimeException("RuntimeException update2: test for rollback");
    }
}
```

calling update method

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        userService.update1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hibernate doesn't support nested transaction rollback.